# How can I increase the time the lock screen is visible before the display turns off?

Tags: display, lock-screen

I am curious if it's possible to adjust the time that the lock screen stays up? Specifically this is when,

1. I intentionally lock the computer with Ctrl + Alt + L
2. Some time passes, I think about 1 minute currently <-- I want to adjust this
3. The screen is powered off automatically

Other questions I have found deal with the situation where the computer is not locked intentionally. I am pretty sure it is powering off the display much faster than the settings those questions refer to indicate.

Context: I would like to work around another problem: the Thunderbolt 3 connection from my laptop's Intel graphics to my 4K @ 60Hz display is a bit finnicky, requiring it to be reconnected several times before getting the right mode. I'd like to still have the security of the lock screen when I step away, but not have to reconnect it. When the display powers off, sometimes this failure often happens. The same issue occurs with a slightly newer work laptop running Linux on the same Thunderbolt 3 monitor. I cannot find any fixes, and I believe it's a newer Intel driver issue, introduced in the past year or so. I have tried another cable, and a Macbook Pro always connects without issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you may use `Unblank lock screen` extension if you're running Ubuntu with default GNOME desktop.

Ubuntu 22.04 can install the extension by using `Extension Manager` app (available in Ubuntu Software). And, old Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 may install it from [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1414/unblank/)

It by default only unblank lock screen when running on AC power, though it has options to make it also work when on battery, and set a time delay (30m, 60m, 90m, 120m, or custom value via `Dconf Editor`) until blank screen.